# Is there builtin way to get a ToggleButton group's current selection?

Tags: python, kivy, togglebutton

I was just browsing through the source in search of a way to do this but didn't see any. I want to be sure though, as I may have missed something. Is there a builtin way, like a method? When I have some `ToggleButton`s that are in a group together, I want to be able to get the value(text value I suppose), of the currently selected(`state == 'down'`) button. I know I can roll my own way to do this without much hassle, but it seems strange that it wouldn't already exist.

After inspection of the docs and the source, I find this to be the easiest way so far:

```
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton as TB

current = [t for t in TB.get_widgets('group') if t.state=='down'][0]
value = current.text
```

While this isn't very long or hard to do, it would be nice to be able to do something like:

**WARNING: Fictional Code**

```
value = TB.get_widgets('group').selected
```

Comment: Up-voting because the Fictional Code warning made me LOL.  The question itself was good too.

Comment: Just remember that if `allow_no_selection` is set, there may be a group without a button in down state.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez Very true. I guess you could maybe wrap the code in a try/except block or something

Answer (score 4):

No that is not possible with builtins. But here is how I would do it:

```
tb = next( (t for t in TB.get_widgets('group') if t.state=='down'), None)
test = tb.text if tb else None
```